# Load in a view after ViewController animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi I am trying to load in a view after I have my view controller animation and I am using the controller identifier "theSetting" as the last line to look for my storyboard ID to get the view, however this method is loading the controller but not loading the view.  Is there anything else I can try to go about this? I am new to using CATransitions and feel like I am leaving something out.  Thank you

```
- (void)bottomButtonScreen4:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Up Worked");

        settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.5;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
        [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:NO];
        [settingsViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theSetting"];


    }
```

Comment: You can do your stuffs in method "viewDidAppear" and check there status of "isViewLoaded" is yes or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your view controller from:

```
settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
```

Then it doesn't have a reference to a `storyboard` so you won't be able to instantiate anything that way.

What you are trying to do should also be done inside the view controller, not in the class you're trying to do it in. If required you should set a property on the view controller so it knows what to do (in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`).